# Can a neural network represent exactly a linear regression?

Tags: neural-networks, multiple-regression

Let's say we have a neural network with one dense hidden layer with two nodes and there are 4 inputs $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$

$y = g(w_{11}f(w_{11}x_1 + w_{21}x_2 + w_{31}x3 + w_{41}x4) + w_{21}f(w_{12}x_1 + w_{22}x_2 + w_{32}x3 + w_{42}x4))$

where $f$ is the activation function for the hidden layer and g is the activation function of the output

the weight $w_{ij}$ are subscripted such that the $i$ refers to the input node's number from the previous layer and the $j$ refers to the current layer's node label.

My question is this:

Clearly if we set $w_{21} = 0$ and let f and g be the identity functions ($f(x) = x, g(x) = x$) then you get

$y = w_{11}x_1 + w_{21}x_2 + w_{31}x3 + w_{41}x4$

which is clearly just reducing to a simple linear regression.

However, if you want to represent interaction terms of say second order, like

$ y = ax_1x_2 + bx_2x_4 + cx_1 + dx_2 +$ etc.

has it been shown that a neural network can be made which is mathematically equivalent to the above??

forgive me if there is well known proof/disproof of this conjecture.

Comment: I guess you could just define the activation functions in such a way as to multiply the argument to some power which would induce interaction terms - then set appropriate coefficients to zero - you should be able to reproduce any linear regression - so i think probably the answer is trivial

Comment: also if this is not the right stack exchange to post this i would appreciate if it could be moved -- there are so many stack exchanges its hard to know what topic belongs where

Comment: Hi: I was trying to find kurt hornik's paper and link to that but I failed so hopefully this link serves a similar purpose. The answer to your question is yes with certain restrictions but it's best to just read this carefully. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/you-dont-understand-neural-networks-until-you-understand-the-universal-approximation-theorem-85b3e7677126

Comment: ah ok, so it can be done with just 1 layer too...

Comment: It's probably best to get hornik's paper to be sure but if that's what the link says i would think that's correct.